# TypeError: Attempted to wrap scrollTo which is already stubbed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I've recently wrote a test for a react component which scrolls the window to the top upon clicking the button.

the test file I wrote worked with no errors on NodeJS 6.9, unfortunately when I upgraded to NodeJS 7.4 I started receiving the error mentioned in the title.

I've spent the past 2 days reading and trying various methods/debugging the issue but I'm stone walled. Any help much appreciated.

all other relevant but not necessary for this question can be seen at its repo:
https://github.com/dirtyredz/react-scroll-up-button

test.js

```
import { jsdom } from 'jsdom';

var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body style="height:2000px"></body></html>');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};

require('raf').polyfill()
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import ScrollUpButton from '../react-scroll-up-button';
import { expect } from 'chai';
//Testing group
describe('Testing <ScrollUpButton/> Action scroll to default top:', ()=>{
  let Component, ScrollTo_Stub;
  before(()=>{
    window.pageYOffset = 0
    //Render component
    Component = mount(<ScrollUpButton />);
    //Settup stub and replace scrollTo function with ours.
    // TypeError: Attempted to wrap scrollTo which is already stubbed
    ScrollTo_Stub = sinon.stub(window, 'scrollTo').callsFake((x,y)=>{
      window.pageXOffset = x;
      window.pageYOffset = y;
    Component.instance().HandleScroll(); // <-- call HandleScroll so the test can simulate the button being toggled
    });
  })
  after(()=>{
    ScrollTo_Stub.restore(); // <-- Restore the objects method
    //window.scrollTo.restore(); // <-- Restore the objects method
  })
  //did it scroll the page up
  it('did scroll the page to 0', (done) => {
    expect(Component.state().ToggleScrollUp).to.equal(''); // <-- Is the button hidden
    window.pageYOffset = 300 // <-- scroll window down to prepare for smulation
    Component.instance().HandleScroll(); // <-- call handleScroll since we scrolled the window down.
    expect(Component.state().ToggleScrollUp).to.equal(true); // <-- Is the button visible
    Component.instance().HandleClick(); // <-- call HandleClick to start the scroll up simulation.
    //Well wait a little bit to let the simulation complete
    setTimeout(()=>{
      expect(ScrollTo_Stub.lastCall.args[1]).to.within(-10,10); // <-- is pageYOffset between -10 and 10
      expect(Component.state().ToggleScrollUp).to.equal(''); // <-- Button should be hidden again
      done() // <-- since were asynchronous with setTimeout instruct chai that were done with the test.
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

**Temp Fix Help**
Please anyone explain why this works and if there is a better way to accomplish this.
Calling this prior to the FIRST `stub()` in the JS file will allow all following stubs to work as expected.

```
window.scrollTo = null;
```

I have consoled.log window.scrollTo prior to this line and after this line. the result is exactly the same. so I have NO clue as to why this makes the code work.